updated MikTeX, now double-prime in mathmode, i.e. $f''(x)$, produces an error "double superscript", any way to avoid this error
As the title suggests, I recently updated MikTeX.  Now every time I write
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage{lmodern}    
\usepackage{microtype}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ccr}  
\usepackage[LGRgreek,frenchmath]{mathastext}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage[sans]{dsfont}                   
\usepackage{bbold}  
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\usepackage{graphicx}                       % need for figures
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{enumitem}     
\def\labelitemi{\,$\bullet$\,}                 
\usepackage[plainpages=false, pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks   = true,
    citecolor    = RoyalBlue,
    linkcolor    = RubineRed,
    urlcolor     = Turquoise
    }
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}         
\usepackage{amssymb}          
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{dsfont}                     
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-tree}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in,paperheight=11in,top=1.00in, bottom=1.00in, left=0.50in, right=0.50in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}       
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true}
\usepackage{fixltx2e,amsmath}       
\MakeRobust{\eqref}
\linespread{1.3}       
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{amsthm}              
\allowdisplaybreaks 
\begin{document} 
\begin{align}
f''
\end{align}
\end{document}

for the second derivative of f in math mode, I get an error.  I know I can fix this with
\begin{align}
f^{\prime\prime}
\end{align}

The problem is, this is not a simple Find-Replace because I also use double apostrophe to to close quotes when I am not in math mode.
Fixing this is going to be a nightmare because I will have to change ALL of my course notes and ALL of my papers.  It's literally thousands of pages that will need to be corrected.
So, if there is any way to tell LaTeX to not produce an error message, that would be best.
NOTE: the above MWE works on my office computer (where I did not update MikTeX).  I only get the error on my home computer (where I DID update MikTeX).

Welcome! Please add a Minimal Working Example (MWE) showing your issue: the simple document \documentclass{article} \begin{document} $f''(x)$ \end{document} works fine

Thanks for the edit, but we will still need a MWE to help: again, a short demo \documentclass{article} \usepackage{amsmath} \begin{document} \begin{align} f'' \end{align} \end{document} works fine.

What you are describing is not the default TeX behavior.  If you still have the error when you run the document Joseph is describing, then something is wrong with your installation.  If you don't have the error with Joseph's document, then something is wrong with the preamble you are using and you'll need to provide more information.

Okay.  I'll try to run @JosephWright MWE on my home computer and see what happens.  If there's no problem, then I'll updated my post here.

Do you get other errors or warnings with a preamble that's almost a decade out of date (at least)?  How much of the preamble can you remove and still have the error with f''?  Does it happen in inline math as well, or just display?

@JohnKormylo Initially, the update didn't work.  And I was not able to reinstall nor uninstall miktex.  But, then I found this thread
https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/1486
The comment at the bottom about running the command prompt in admin mode worked for me.

Update
Version 1.4e of mathastext has fixed the issue.
Answer for mathastext with version 1.4c (earlier versions aren't affected)
The culprit is mathastext that makes a bad error: it defines the active ' as
\ifmmode\mst@active@math@prime\else'\fi

but this is wrong, as \mst@active@math@prime will always see \else after it and never another '.
The fix is “easy”: just before \begin{document} add
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`'\lowercase{%
    \endgroup\def~}{\ifmmode\expandafter\mst@active@math@prime \else '\fi}%
}
\makeatother

and your f'' will show up perfectly.
I have several objections on the organization of your preamble, but they're off topic.

I filed a bug report.

Thanks!  Your solution worked!

Feel free to explain your objections to the organization of my preamble.  I am more than happy to clean it up (would like to, actually).
